# Bootstrap responsive navbar with a leftmost logo followed with menu items all on navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Instead of using the branding of Bootstrap 3, I am after a responsive navbar that has my logo at the leftmost position of the navbar with required menu options just next to the logo on the navbar.

The issue I am not sure how to handle is that, as I want this navbar to be responsive, when the screen size is reduced to say a iPhone size, I want my typical Bootstrap hamburger menu positioned to the right-most of the navbar and when pressed, will reveal my menu items only but at the same time, I want my logo to always maintain the left-most position on my navbar, no matter what screen resolution is used.

I have provided the basic structure of what I have at the moment but unsure how to include my logo or for examples sake, a link for now to always remain on the navbar and always at the left-most position.

I have created http://www.bootply.com/HcZhCxMC4s for sample but it's not perfect as I am unsure how to position logo/link with menu items.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <ul class="my-logo">
        <li><a href="#">Logo Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you put this on fiddle?

Comment: added link to a Bootply above - http://www.bootply.com/HcZhCxMC4s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the same markup of the Bootstrap Navbar ...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    /*YOUR LOGO OR LINK HERE WITH THE CLASS NAVBAR-BRAND*/    
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo Link</a>
```

Check the **[BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/TZuRyT2oFS)**

Answer (score 0):

you may want to add some styling:

css:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-header {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
     top:0;
  }
  .my-logo {
    height: 50px;    
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0
  }
  .my-logo li a {
      line-height: 50px;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/9KstQ2THvF#

Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

simplest answer on bootstrap's [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image) page :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="...">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```